# strange user profiles in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have strange user profiles in MySQL users table.

when I type this command:

> mysql> SELECT User, Host, authentication_string FROM mysql.user;

this is the output:

```
+------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| User             | Host      | authentication_string                                                  |
+------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
=A8kOOKZFfLtuvjSt/4N2vBczVh/x86enOUrQ3.nvYx6 |{uM
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | $A$005$t&+b*T~?URhAKh6vNu/poypI3.fHxo3x/6JlNWzgUqF5gSbYeP/ |
`wb7I\0zvKHFsJLJvxhIr1m1Vdj/qOp6NcuqSTsXwoYy/Gsd. |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| mysql.session    | localhost | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| root             | localhost |                                                                        |
+------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

how can I remove strange profiles in the first and third row?

when I type:

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

output is:

```
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| monitor          | %         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| monitor          | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `authentication_string` is data for the authentication plugin whose name is stored in `plugin`-column.

You could first see what are these `monitor`-entries:

```
SELECT User, Host, plugin 
FROM mysql.user 
WHERE User='monitor';
```

And if you do not need them, drop the users:

```
DROP USER 'monitor'@'%';
DROP USER 'monitor'@'localhost';
```

The content of the authentication_string depends on the authentication plugin being used (see plugin-column value). It used to be called password, but as it can contain other than passwords, the name was changed to authentication_string. In your case, the column just happens to contain control characters that your terminal uses. Nothing to worry about. You can always use another client to see the content.

Comment: I created these `monitor` users. I need them for monitoring from remote computer.

Comment: What is the plugin-column value for those users? So what is the actual problem that you have (other than the data in `authentication_string`-column does not show up correctly)?

Comment: The only issue I have is that data in `authentication_string`-column does not show up correctly.

Comment: The content of the `authentication_string` depends on the authentication plugin being used (see plugin-column value). It used to be called `password`, but as it can contain other than passwords, the name wasn changed to `authentication_string`. In your case the column just happens to contain control characters that yout terminal uses. Nothing to worry about. You can always use another client to see the content.